# Errors using built-in comment framework

Tags: django, django-forms, django-comments

I'm trying to use the built-in comment framework but I cannot get it to work. Here's the code:

```
#view.py
from django.contrib.comments.forms import *
from forms import *
from models import *

def view_item_detail(request, item_id):
    item = Item.manager.get(item_id)
    form = CommentForm(item)

    if request.POST:
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_comment = form.save(commit=False)
            # do stuff here
            new_comment.save()
            messages.success(request, "Your comment was successfully posted!")
            return HttpResponseRedirect("")

    return render_to_response('item_detail.html', 
                          RequestContext(request, {'item': item, 
                                    'authentication': request.user.is_authenticated(), 
                                    'user': request.user, 'form': form}))
```

and

```
#item_detail.html
{% if authentication %}
    {% if form %}
        <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
            {{ form }}
            <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit comment" /></p>
        </form>
    {% endif %}
{% else %}
    <p>You must be logged-in to post a comment</p>
{% endif %}
```

The error I'm getting is "'QueryDict' object has no attribute '_meta'" which is coming from the line

```
form = CommentForm(request.POST)
```

Any help would be appreciated, cheers.

Comment: while not part of the solution you should be cautious of using `if request.POST:`, rather use `if request.method == 'POST':`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry after reading your comments to my last answer you don't need to include the comment form in your view if you are using the built in comment framework:

```
from forms import *
from models import *

def view_item_detail(request, item_id):
    item = get_object_or_404(Item, pk=item_id)

    return render_to_response('item_detail.html', 
                          RequestContext(request, {'item': item, 
                                    'authentication': request.user.is_authenticated(), 
                                    'user': request.user,}))
```

now make sure you have this in your urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    (r'^comments/', include('django.contrib.comments.urls')),
    ...
)
```

and `'django.contrib.comments'` added to your INSTALLED_APPS, and syncdb'd

now in your `item_detail.html` file you should add:

```
{% load comments %}
```

where you want the comments displayed:

```
{% render_comment_list for item %}
```

where you want the add comments form displayed:

```
{% if authentication %}
    {% get_comment_form for item as form %}
    <form action="{% comment_form_target %}" method="post">
        {{ form }}
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="preview" class="submit-post" value="Preview"></td>
        </tr>
    </form>
{% endif %}
```

read the docs [**`here`**](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/comments/#quick-start-guide) and for customization read [**`this`**](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/comments/custom/) page.

as part of the docs:

> To specify the URL you want to
>   redirect to after the comment has been
>   posted, you can include a hidden form
>   input called next in your comment
>   form. For example:

```
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{% url my_comment_was_posted %}" />
```

(edited for your example):

```
{% if authentication %}
    {% get_comment_form for item as form %}
    <form action="{% comment_form_target %}" method="post">
        {{ form }}
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ item.get_absolute_url }}" />
            <td><input type="submit" name="preview" class="submit-post" value="Preview"></td>
        </tr>
    </form>
{% else %}
    <p>You must be logged-in to post a comment</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't clarify this but what I wanted was for someone to post a comment about an item and have the comment appear on the same page. (item_detail.html). In the above answer, (r'^comments/', include('django.contrib.comments.urls')) would send the user to a different page if I'm right and I don't want to do that. I want to use their framework but I want everything redirected to the same webpage. Is there a way to do this apart from creating a custom comment class?

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm. Just need to get rid of the preview page and I'm set